# Custom position of toolbar in TinyMCE rich text editor

Tags: tinymce

I am trying to use TinyMCE in my project.
In the examples i saw that toolbar can be either always be visible or just added when user is inside the editor. What i want, is for toolbar be always visible, but in the predifined position in the page. I.E
  some header

some other content

some footer.

Can it be done? what are the TinyMCE configurations needed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to place the tinymce toolbar on top or bellow your editor field, additionally you can place the toolbar in a div of your choice somewhere on your page.
Have a look at the tinymce wiki regarding the configuration parameter [theme_advanced_toolbar_location](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/theme_advanced_toolbar_location).

Comment: Heads up, the link is broken.

Comment: indeed, it is. moxiecode is working on their website. guess they fiddle with the docs to make it compatible to tinymce4